# how can i check the voice channel ID that the person is after they execute a command and move to other voice channel in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need to check the voice channel ID that the person is on after they execute a command. If it is on this channel, I want the bot to move to another desired channel.

```
      var idchannel = member.get.voiceChannelID;
      if(idchannel === "ID"){
      //command
      // and i need to move this user to another channel.
    }
    else {
      message.reply("You are not on the correct Channel.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As of Discord.js v12, my original answer will no longer work due to changes in voice related features.

Assuming you have a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember) `member`, you are able to access voice related options using [`member.voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice). Through that [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState), you can refer to the [`VoiceState#channelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channelID) property to access the ID of the [VoiceChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceConnection) the member is connected to, if any. Putting it together, that's `member.voice.channelID`.

As for moving the member to a specific channel, you'd do so using the [`VoiceState#setChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel) method, so `member.voice.setChannel(...)`.

The updated code would look something like the following:

```js
const voiceChannelID = member.voice.channelID;
if (voiceChannelID === 'some channel ID') {
  member.voice.setChannel('target channel ID') // you may want to await this, async fn required
    .catch(console.error);
} else {
  message.reply('You are not in the correct channel.') // see last comment
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL (v11):**

You can refer to the voice channel a user is connected to using [`GuildMember.voiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voiceChannel). Then check the channel's [`id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=id) property against the expected ID.

To move a member from one voice channel to another, you can use the [`GuildMember.setVoiceChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setVoiceChannel) method.

```js
const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel; // Keep in mind this may be undefined if
                                                  // they aren't connected to any channel.

if (voiceChannel && voiceChannel.id === "channel ID") {
  message.member.setVoiceChannel(/* some other channel or ID */);
} else message.reply("You are not in the correct channel.");
```

<sub>*Make sure to catch any errors from your promises. See [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Error_propagation).*</sub>

Comment: thanks. And, you know about move any people in that channel to other channel?

Comment: @Johnyttw Move the user or move the client/bot?

Comment: move the user to other channel

Comment: @Johnyttw I've edited the answer to show how to do so.

Comment: It's `message.member.voice.channel` now (discord.js v12).